# Can you level up after finishing the main story and not having a PSPlus subscription?

Tags: ps4, destiny

I'm at Level 20 and have finished the main story line.  I am unable to play in The Crucible or participate in Strike missions because I don't have a Playstation Plus subscription.  Now that the Loot Cave has been patched, is there any way for me to get legendary gear or motes of light for leveling up by completing the regular patrol missions that are still available for me to play?

Comment: You should have access to the daily missions too, with the recent patch you will be getting engrams after completing this, they will always be blue or higher. The higher the level of the daily mission the better the reward and the more engrams that are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be difficult, but yes. It is still possible. By completing bounties and patrol missions, you will eventually be able to afford legendary equipment sold by vendors, which will boost your Light level quite dramatically.

Comment: It's probably best not to bother mentioning any loot caves as a definitive answer. They'll all be 'fixed' in one way or another eventually, making the answer outdated.

Comment: @MichaelFrank edited.

Answer (score 0):

They may have patched **The Legendary Loot Cave**, but there are other loot caves (if you're into that). One is on the Cosmodrome. Simply spawn, turn 45 degrees to the right, and walk into the building. Go down the stairs, find a staircase, and move slightly onto the staircase. Then you just have to wait for enemies to spawn.

Dropships will mess up the spawn.